# How can I make a nested element span across the full screen width if it is inheriting a max-width style?

Tags: html, css

I have included a snippet of my example attempt below.

It almost works apart from the fact that the 3rd paragraph does not follow on after the 2nd paragraph.

**Update: I've found a solution. @Paul's last comment inspired me. :) I've posted my solution in the answers**

```css
#full-width {
  position: absolute; 
  left: 0; 
  width: 100vw; 
  border: 3px solid #73AD21;
}
```

```html
<div style="max-width:300px; border: 3px solid #73AD21; margin:auto">

  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Etiam semper diam at erat pulvinar, at pulvinar felis blandit. Vestibulum volutpat tellus diam, consequat gravida libero rhoncus ut. Maecenas imperdiet felis nisi, fringilla luctus felis hendrerit sit amet. Pellentesque interdum, nisl nec interdum maximus, augue diam porttitor lorem, et sollicitudin felis neque sit amet erat.</p>

  <div id="full-width">  
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Etiam semper diam at erat pulvinar, at    pulvinar felis blandit. Vestibulum volutpat tellus diam, consequat gravida libero rhoncus ut. Maecenas imperdiet felis nisi, fringilla luctus felis hendrerit sit amet. Pellentesque interdum, nisl nec interdum maximus, augue diam porttitor lorem, et sollicitudin felis neque sit amet erat.</p>    
  </div>
  
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Etiam semper diam at erat pulvinar, at pulvinar felis blandit. Vestibulum volutpat tellus diam, consequat gravida libero rhoncus ut. Maecenas imperdiet felis nisi, fringilla luctus felis hendrerit sit amet. Pellentesque interdum, nisl nec interdum maximus, augue diam porttitor lorem, et sollicitudin felis neque sit amet erat.</p>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the answers provided will be useful to others.

However I do have the restriction that the nested element must inherit the max-width from the outer div otherwise it will add big complications to my code.

However, @Paul's last comment did inspire me to create this answer, which has solved my problem. :)

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

  var fill_size_required = $('#full-width').height()
  $('#filler').css('height',fill_size_required);

});
```

```css
#full-width {
  position: absolute; 
  left: 0; 
  width: 100vw; 
  border: 3px solid #73AD21;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div style="max-width:300px; border: 3px solid #73AD21; margin:auto">

  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Etiam semper diam at erat pulvinar, at pulvinar felis blandit. Vestibulum volutpat tellus diam, consequat gravida libero rhoncus ut. Maecenas imperdiet felis nisi, fringilla luctus felis hendrerit sit amet. Pellentesque interdum, nisl nec interdum maximus, augue diam porttitor lorem, et sollicitudin felis neque sit amet erat.</p>

  <div id="full-width">  
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Etiam semper diam at erat pulvinar, at    pulvinar felis blandit. Vestibulum volutpat tellus diam, consequat gravida libero rhoncus ut. Maecenas imperdiet felis nisi, fringilla luctus felis hendrerit sit amet. Pellentesque interdum, nisl nec interdum maximus, augue diam porttitor lorem, et sollicitudin felis neque sit amet erat.</p>    
  </div>  
  <div id="filler"> </div>
  
  
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Etiam semper diam at erat pulvinar, at pulvinar felis blandit. Vestibulum volutpat tellus diam, consequat gravida libero rhoncus ut. Maecenas imperdiet felis nisi, fringilla luctus felis hendrerit sit amet. Pellentesque interdum, nisl nec interdum maximus, augue diam porttitor lorem, et sollicitudin felis neque sit amet erat.</p>

</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you won't be able to get that working that way. Due to your absolute positioning the full width div doesn't occupy any space anymore and that's why the following paragraph and the absolute positioned paragraph are overlapping.

It does work, if you create three divs (the first and the last one with max-width and the middle one with full width.

```css
#full-width {
  width: 100%;
  border: 3px solid #73AD21;
}

.max-width {
  max-width: 300px;
  margin: auto;
  border: 3px solid #73AD21;
}
```

```html
<div class="max-width">

  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Etiam semper diam at erat pulvinar, at pulvinar felis blandit. Vestibulum volutpat tellus diam, consequat gravida libero rhoncus ut. Maecenas imperdiet felis nisi, fringilla luctus felis hendrerit
    sit amet. Pellentesque interdum, nisl nec interdum maximus, augue diam porttitor lorem, et sollicitudin felis neque sit amet erat.</p>
</div>

<div id="full-width">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Etiam semper diam at erat pulvinar, at pulvinar felis blandit. Vestibulum volutpat tellus diam, consequat gravida libero rhoncus ut. Maecenas imperdiet felis nisi, fringilla luctus felis hendrerit
    sit amet. Pellentesque interdum, nisl nec interdum maximus, augue diam porttitor lorem, et sollicitudin felis neque sit amet erat.</p>
</div>

<div class="max-width">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Etiam semper diam at erat pulvinar, at pulvinar felis blandit. Vestibulum volutpat tellus diam, consequat gravida libero rhoncus ut. Maecenas imperdiet felis nisi, fringilla luctus felis hendrerit
    sit amet. Pellentesque interdum, nisl nec interdum maximus, augue diam porttitor lorem, et sollicitudin felis neque sit amet erat.</p>

</div>
```

If you cannot do this, you need to add a fixed margin-top to the last div, which has the same number of pixels as the height of the second paragraph. Nevertheless that's a not a nice solution.

Answer (score 1):

you can try this .if you give position absolute than for the third paragraph need to give margin-top to resolve overflow.

```css
    #full-width p{
  position:relative;
  width:100vw; 
  max-width:100%;
  border: 3px solid #73AD21;
  margin-left:0;
}
p{
  max-width:300px; 
  border: 3px solid #73AD21; 
  margin:auto;
}
```

```html
<div>

  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Etiam semper diam at erat pulvinar, at pulvinar felis blandit. Vestibulum volutpat tellus diam, consequat gravida libero rhoncus ut. Maecenas imperdiet felis nisi, fringilla luctus felis hendrerit sit amet. Pellentesque interdum, nisl nec interdum maximus, augue diam porttitor lorem, et sollicitudin felis neque sit amet erat.</p>

  <div id="full-width">  
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Etiam semper diam at erat pulvinar, at    pulvinar felis blandit. Vestibulum volutpat tellus diam, consequat gravida libero rhoncus ut. Maecenas imperdiet felis nisi, fringilla luctus felis hendrerit sit amet. Pellentesque interdum, nisl nec interdum maximus, augue diam porttitor lorem, et sollicitudin felis neque sit amet erat.</p>    
  </div>
  
  <p>Lsdxsorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Etiam semper diam at erat pulvinar, at pulvinar felis blandit. Vestibulum volutpat tellus diam, consequat gravida libero rhoncus ut. Maecenas imperdiet felis nisi, fringilla luctus felis hendrerit sit amet. Pellentesque interdum, nisl nec interdum maximus, augue diam porttitor lorem, et sollicitudin felis neque sit amet erat.</p>

</div>
```